# Link and hover not working in jumbotron

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap framework and what i am trying to achive is putting a background image over gradient with the following code:

```
jumbotron{
  position: relative;
  padding: 60px 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%, #6D3353 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0px -3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  }   

.jumbotron:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: url('css/bs-docs-masthead-pattern.png') repeat scroll center center transparent;
  opacity: 0.4;
  }
```

The problem i am facing is that when i use the `position: absolute` property in `jumbotron:after` all the **link and hover** (but i get an image over gradient) property ceases to exist. And when I don't use it, i don't get an image (but the link and hover property works).
Is there any way to get both the things at the same time w/o messing up the layout?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making an overlay with `:after` pseudo element, try to set up two gradients on jumbotron itself:

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    padding: 60px 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    background: 
        url('css/bs-docs-masthead-pattern.png') repeat scroll center center,
        linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%, #6D3353 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0px -3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
}
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z64z6U28fff8jDEB3xgn?p=preview